# How to communicate with SMS gateway via PHP

Tags: php

I have a link I need users to click in order for them to receive a text message. The URL points to an external link so I can't mask it. At present when a user clicks on the link I redirect them to the external site to send the message, but I do not wish to do this as I don't want the user to see the external URL.

I have tried to use `file_get_contents()` and cURL but I have been unable to get either mechanism to work. When I load the page in the browser I get the text response "OK", when I use PHP to make the request I get the "OK" response from the server but I do not receive the text message to my phone.

Here is the cURL code I have tried:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
```

Comment: How do you submit the phone number to that other website?

Comment: Please note that English does not mandate an exclamation mark at the end of every sentence.

Comment: We need to see the URL you are using for the link (you can use a different domain if you wish) and we need to see the contents of the `$url` variable.

Comment: you can also skip the external script and send the message directly to the the phone using the carrier's email to SMS gateway. Most carriers have on that defines an email address for every phone, (555) 313 - 0000 turns into `5553130000@carriertext.com`. Here is a list of the gateways http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Answer (score 1):

Using twilio may be able to save you some time here.

Note: Only wrote this here because I cant comment for some reason.

Comment: I also use this service... way easy to setup and use